# SVN check out revision number

Tags: svn

I was wondering whether anyone knew of a way to look up what revision number you checked out your code from an SVN repository.  In other words, I was wondering if there was any combination of functions or an svn command in which you would type something about the working copy and you can get back the revision in which it was checked out from the repository.  The purpose for this is when multiple people are committing to a repository and you want to check what was changed from the original copy to your working copy.  Thank you and all help is much appreciated.

Comment: What's wrong with just doing a diff against the base (the default behavior)?

Comment: Doing a diff against BASE gives you the difference between the first time you committed and your current changes, doesn't it?  Or does it give you the diff between the version you first checked out and your current working copy?

Comment: If I did `svn diff -r BASE $svnrepo`, wouldn't that get me my desired output? It is grabbing the working copy's revision from before I first made changes, checking that revision number in my svnrepo, and then doing a diff against my current working copy's changes.

Comment: Figured it out thanks to Ic.  The way you figure it out is you do a svn diff against the BASE copy and your current working copy.  In perl this can be done with `my @output = svn diff $workingcopy;`  What this does is it grabs the BASE revision or in other words the last time you committed to the SVN repository or did an svn update, and compares that revision to the changes you made in your working directory.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I was hinting at/asking about. Feel free to write yourself an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out thanks to Ic. The way you figure it out is you do a svn diff against the BASE copy and your current working copy. In perl this can be done with `my @output = svn diff $workingcopy;` What this does is it grabs the BASE revision or in other words the last time you committed to the SVN repository or did an svn update, and compares that revision to the changes you made in your working directory.